# Zend framework form structure for wrap form element with html tag

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Can anyone help me to make html like this in Zend framework?

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      <span>Add files...</span>
      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
```

I am using this code but not get same like what I want

```
$photo = new Zend_Form_Element_File('photo');
    $photo->setLabel($this->_translate->_('pictures') . ':')
            ->addValidator('IsImage')
            ->addValidator('Size', false, 204800)
            ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif')
            ->setDestination($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads')
            ->setValueDisabled(true)
            ->setAttrib('multiple', 'multiple')
            ->setIsArray(true)
            ->removeDecorator('Label');

....
....
$this->addElements(array($photo));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag` or write your own decorator. There are [two brief examples here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/08/07/zend_form-decorator-tips/) but this site is a bit old - so be sure to also check the [documentation of Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/files/Form.Decorator.HtmlTag.html#Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag)

Comment: Yes I can get only wrap span like
<span><input type="file" /></span>

I want to add one span and icon tag in wrap span also

Comment: The website includes examples on how to add tags only before or after your form element - but you will probably be much better off writing your own decorator.

Comment: Actually I am fresher for Zend framework So.. Can you show me or guide me how to create decorator and where I can place in folder?

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/ contains a lot of information to get started.